# How to merge two equations, taking into account the size of the variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following equations:

$X(t) \cdot e=v\\c \cdot X(t)=S(t-1)-S(t)-V(t)$

Where $X(t)$ is a $(1,n)$ vector, $S(t)$ a $(1,n)$ vector and $V(t)$ a $(1,n)$ vector and $c$, $v$ are number (Among the previous variables, some are time dependent). $e$ is the unit vector of dimension $(n,1)$.

How can I merge these 2 equations in one to obtain a single equation (linear of $X$) ?

I believe that one way of doing it is to actually transform the number $c$ in a $(n,n)$ matrix $c'$ of which every element is equal to $c$, transform the number $v$ in a $(1,n)$ vector $v'$ of which every element is equal to $v$ and transform $e=(1,1,1,...)$ in the unit matrix $e'$.
Then I have the following:
$$X(t) \cdot (c'+e')=S(t-1)-S(t)-V(t)+v'$$

Comment: The way to combine equations in linear algebra is not to add them but to stack them. For example, $u^Tx=a,v^Tx=b \iff \begin{bmatrix}u^T\\v^T\end{bmatrix}x=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$ (assuming column vectors). If you simply add the equations you will get extra solutions that do not satisfy the original equations.

Comment: Yes, true and very logical. Mea culpa and thank you. Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it ?